# Creating multiple dataframes

Tags: r

I would like to create multiple DFs, where each new DF only contains observations for that student. Currently, I create a new DF using the following code. Which I repeat, changing the students name.

```
James <- All_Results [which(All_Results$`Student.x` =='James'),]
```

DF: All_Results

```
 Student  Score_Jan  Score_Feb  Score Mar
 James       12          76          23
 James       52          86          63     
 James       19          74          83
 Nick        72          26          54
 Nick        92          16          43
 Nick        12          76          23
 Tony        87          36          52
 Tony        22          46          33
```

How can I do this if I have the following

```
 c(James, Nick, Tony)
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `length` of the `vector` is greater than or equal to 1, `%in%` is an option

```
newdat <- All_Results[All_Results$`Student.x` %in% c('James', 'Nick', 'Tony'),]
```

It would also take care of the `NA` elements, so there is no need to wrap with `which`

---

If the intention is to create separate data.frames, then use `split`

```
lst1 <- split(All_Results, All_Results$`Student.x`)
```

If we want only a subset of elements, then use the 'newdat' created earlier

```
lst1 <- split(newdat, new$`Student.x`)
```

It will return a `list` of `data.frame`s. It is not advisable to create multiple data.frame objects in the global environment.  But, it can be done with `assign` or `list2env`

```
list2env(lst1, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: @skrun - Thank you very much for your help. I keep getting the following error "Error in new$student : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: @CISCO. Can you check the `str` of your data.  I assume that it is a normal column

Comment: Thanks @akrun - that was the proble, All fixed up now.